# Consolidate search refiners

Tags: search, refiner

Is it possible to consolidate refiners in search on a SharePoint Online site into a single value, i.e. MA, Mass, Massachusetts would consolidate into Mass. I think it's a dictionary, but when trying to add a dictionary we don't see to have that option.